# Multiple selection in drop down list, but exclude one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a VBA code (that I found online, I'm not very good at VBA) to select multiple items from a drop down list. However I'd like for one of the cells in my Workbook (cell $D$3) to not be affected by this macro. So while it has data validation, you could only select one option. Any help appreciated, I'm trying to learn!

Here's the code I used

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Updated by Extendoffice 2019/11/13
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Or _
                   InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) Or _
                   InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") Then
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                Else
                    Target.Value = xValue1 & ", " & xValue2
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You could add `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

BigBen commented an answer which solved my problem, thank you!

Here is the revised version which has worked for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Updated by Extendoffice 2019/11/13
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Or _
                   InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) Or _
                   InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") Then
                    Target.Value = xValue1
```